# What do you call the components of a visual pattern?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Imagine a field of dots.** If these dots are regularly spaced according to some geometric logic, whether in an even grid or a more complex arrangement, you have a pattern. It is a pattern of dots.

But now let us replace these dots with stars. Now you have a pattern of stars. The arrangement is the pattern; the component is the star.

We could then replace this star with a cross, or a circle, or so forth.

**What do we generically call these dots, stars and crosses – that is, the components of the pattern?**

I am inclined to call them *pips*, the symbols on a playing card, or to call them all dots, regardless of the shape. Is there a more established name?

Comment: *Symbolic characters* should work.

Comment: @DJohnson - or simply *symbols*

Comment: @Jim & DJohnson I often lean toward *symbol* but by definition symbol refers to representation, which is not always true of these dots in a pattern

Comment: patterns of dots=a dotted pattern;  a starred pattern. Those are possibilities.

Comment: @unrelated It sounds like you've assumed that the *representation* has to have a specific meaning assigned to the symbol which could be numeric or linguistic. A good counterfactual to that assumption is Dan Sperber's comment that "symbols are meaning without language." Sperber is a French cognitive anthropologist who has written extensively about cross-cultural evolution and issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a repeating spatial pattern (as opposed to say a fractal), the basic component is usually called a **motif**.

From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/motif):

> motif [noun]
>
> 1A decorative image or design, especially a repeated one forming a
>   pattern.

But this is probably best considered as the tessellating component. The stars, flowers, birds, ships ... included within the tesserae (which may not be outlined) are usually referred to indirectly: 'a pattern of stars' / 'a pattern of roses'.

Comment: But doesn't a motif maintain it's own distinct identity in the finished work? I'm working under the impression that the choice of dot or star or cross would not be noticeable in the final image. Stars are a motif of many national flags, but are dots a motif of [this](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sun-sunburst-pattern-made-stipples-dots-471034865)?

Comment: How can that be considered a repeating pattern? / Note that there is not a single definition for 'motif'; I've selected the 'especially a repeated one forming a pattern'. A repeating pattern is an infinite 'ribbon' pattern, essentially 1-D,  or a tessellation in 2-D (or a crystal structure in 3-D).

Answer (score 1):

For small shapes that loose their own identity in the final image, I would use **stipple**

[Sun Sunburst Pattern made of stipples. Dots texture on rays. Vector illustration](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sun-sunburst-pattern-made-stipples-dots-471034865)

Answer (score 0):

Other than components that you mention, you could refer to them as elements, members, or constituents of the pattern, but all three have other meanings as well. The word element seems to come closest to defining the parts of a greater pattern